# Array items from localStorage not appearing on page

Tags: javascript, html

Here Html code of main page where i have blocks of items with ids with heart icon, when click to favorite-icon it turn red and added to favorites page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kolca</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&family=Onest:wght@400;600&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300;500&family=Source+Serif+4:opsz,wght@8..60,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-sergi.css">
</head>
<body class="page">
    <div class="page__row">
        <div class="page__cell">
            <header class="header">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="menu-list">
                        <li>
                            <div class="menu">
                            <img src="meny.png" alt="" class="menu_logo" width="50px" height="45px"> 
                            </div>
                            <ul class="sub_menu__list">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="sergi.html" class="sub-menu__link">Серьги</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="shekelik.html" class="sub-menu__link">Шекелик</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Shashbau.html" class="sub-menu__link">Шашбау</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Brasleti.html" class="sub-menu__link">Браслеты</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="kolsa.html" class="sub-menu__link">Кольца</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Besbilezik.html" class="sub-menu__link">Бесбилезик</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Ohzerelye.html" class="sub-menu__link">Ожерелье</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Komlekti.html" class="sub-menu__link">Комплекты</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <a href="vitrina.html" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo__picture" src="logoandlineunderlogo.png" alt="" width="336.5px" height="107.5px">
                    </a>
                
                <a href="favourite.html" class="favourite">
                    
                    <img src="favourite.png" alt="" class="favorite_picture" width="80px" height="75px">
                </a>
                <a href="Main Info.html" class="name">ARAFAI
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-row">
        <div class="title">
    <center>Кольца</center>
    </div>
    <hr width="100%">
</div>
    <div class="page-row">
        <div class="page__cell">
            <div class="block-main">
                <div class="image2">
                    <img src="blocksergi.jpg" alt="Your Image 1" width="675px">
                </div>
                <div class="text2">
                    
                        <p>Кольца всегда были неотъемлемой частью образа казахских красавиц. Считалось хорошим тоном носить несколько колец одновременно. Эта традиция актуальна и по сей день. С давних времен этим кольцам приписывали магические свойства и считали, что они обладают чудодейственной силой, защищая от злых духов. Поэтому два, три и даже четыре кольца на руках казахской женщины были обыденной "нормой"."Этнические кольца" являются вдохновением для традиционных культур и искусства разных народов. Эти кольца часто изготавливаются с использованием ручной работы и воплощают в себе богатство традиций и символику. Они могут быть украшены геометрическими узорами, яркими камнями, или даже символами, отражающими национальные ценности и историю.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr width="90%" color="#af936c">
        <div class="block" data-id="1">
        <img src="gridlayout/img1.jpg" alt="1" >
        <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon far fa-heart"></i>
            <h3>Jewelry Piece 1</h3>
            <p>Description of the jewelry piece goes here.</p>
            <h4>Price: $100.00</h4>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="block" data-id="2">
        <img src="gridlayout/img1.jpg" alt="2" >
        <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon far fa-heart" ></i>
            <h3>Jewelry Piece 2</h3>
            <p>Description of the jewelry piece goes here.</p>
            <h4>Price: $150.00</h4>
        </div>
   
    </div>

    <div class="block" data-id="3">
        <img src="gridlayout/img1.jpg" alt="3" >
        <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon far fa-heart" ></i>
            <h3>Jewelry Piece 1</h3>
            <p>Description of the jewelry piece goes here.</p>
            <h4>Price: $100.00</h4>
        </div>
        
       
    </div>
    <div class="block" data-id="4">
        <img src="gridlayout/img1.jpg" alt="4" >
        <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon far fa-heart"></i>
            <h3>Jewelry Piece 1</h3>
            <p>Description of the jewelry piece goes here.</p>
            <h4>Price: $100.00</h4>
        </div>
        
       
    </div>
     <div class="block" data-id="5">
        <img src="gridlayout/img1.jpg" alt="5" >
        <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon far fa-heart" ></i>
            <h3>Beautiful Diamond Necklace</h3>
            <p>Description of the jewelry piece goes here.</p>
        <h4>Price: $500</h4>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="block" data-id="6">
        <img src="gridlayout/img1.jpg" alt="6" >
        <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon far fa-heart"></i>
        <h3>Elegant Pearl Earrings</h3>
        <p>Description of the jewelry piece goes here.</p>
        <h4>Price: $250</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="page__row page__row--footer">
        <div class="page_cell">
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-cool">
                    
                    <h3>О нас</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-cool"><h3>Наши контакты</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>+7 705 408 4570</li>
                        <li>+7 771 277 1687</li>    
                        <li>+7 705 816 4212</li>
                        <li>+7 707 702 3939</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-cool"><h3>Наш адрес</h3>
                    <a href=""><img src="иконки/adres.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-cool"><h3>Наши соцсети</h3> 
                    <a href="@"><img src="иконки/inst.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="@"><img src="иконки/pint.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="@"><img src="иконки/watsap.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/newscript.js" defer></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

and this is newscript.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Retrieve from localStorage when the page loads
  const favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];

  // Function to toggle the favorite status
  function toggleFavoriteStatus(icon, itemId) {
    // Toggle item in favorites page
    if (!favorites.includes(itemId)) {
      // Add item to favorites
      favorites.push(itemId);
      // Add "fas" and remove "far" when adding to favorites
      icon.classList.remove('far');
      icon.classList.add('fas');
    } else {
      // Remove item from favorites
      const indexToRemove = favorites.indexOf(itemId);
      if (indexToRemove !== -1) {
        favorites.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
        // Add "far" and remove "fas" when removing from favorites
        icon.classList.remove('fas');
        icon.classList.add('far');
      }
    }
// Log all items in the main page
const allItemsInMainPage = document.querySelectorAll('.block');
console.log('All items in the main page:', Array.from(allItemsInMainPage).map(item => item.getAttribute('data-id')));

    // Save the updated favorites to localStorage after each click
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
  }
console.log('Data IDs in Main Page:', Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.block')).map(el => el.getAttribute('data-id')));
  const favoriteIcons = document.querySelectorAll('.favorite-icon');

  favoriteIcons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // Toggle item in favorites page
      const item = icon.closest('.block');
      const itemId = item.getAttribute('data-id'); // Assuming there's a data-id attribute

      toggleFavoriteStatus(icon, itemId);
    });

    // Initialize the icons based on whether the item is in favorites
    const item = icon.closest('.block');
    const itemId = item.getAttribute('data-id');
    if (favorites.includes(itemId)) {
      // If the item is in favorites, set the "fas" class
      icon.classList.add('fas');
    } else {
      // If the item is not in favorites, set the "far" class
      icon.classList.add('far');
    }
  });
});
```

This is favorites page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Favourite</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa:wght@300&family=Onest:wght@400;600&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@300;500&family=Source+Serif+4:opsz,wght@8..60,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="favourite-style.css">
</head>
<body class="page">
    <div class="page__row">
        <div class="page__cell">
            <header class="header">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul class="menu-list">
                        <li>
                            <a href="@" class="menu">
                            <img src="meny.png" alt="" class="menu_logo" width="50px" height="45px">
                            </a>
                            <ul class="sub_menu__list">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="sergi.html" class="sub-menu__link">Серьги</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="shekelik.html" class="sub-menu__link">Шекелик</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Shashbau.html" class="sub-menu__link">Шашбау</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Brasleti.html" class="sub-menu__link">Браслеты</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="kolsa.html" class="sub-menu__link">Кольца</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Besbilezik.html" class="sub-menu__link">Бесбилезик</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Ohzerelye.html" class="sub-menu__link">Ожерелье</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="Komlekti.html" class="sub-menu__link">Комплекты</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <a href="vitrina.html" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo__picture" src="logoandlineunderlogo.png" alt="" width="336.5px" height="107.5px">
                    </a>
                
                <a href="@" class="favourite">
                    <img src="favourite.png" alt="" class="favorite_picture" width="80px" height="75px">
                </a>
                <a href="@" class="name">ARAFAI
                </a>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-row">
        <div class="title">
    <center>Избранное</center>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <hr width="90%" color="#af936c">
 <div id="favorites-page">
    <!-- Items will be added/removed here dynamically -->
  </div>
    
    <div class="page__row page__row--footer">
        <div class="page___cell">
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-cool">
                    
                    <h3>О нас</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-cool"><h3>Наши контакты</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>+7 705 408 4570</li>
                        <li>+7 771 277 1687</li>    
                        <li>+7 705 816 4212</li>
                        <li>+7 707 702 3939</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-cool"><h3>Наш адрес</h3>
                    <a href=""><img src="иконки/adres.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-cool"><h3>Наши соцсети</h3> 
                    <a href="@"><img src="иконки/inst.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="@"><img src="иконки/pint.png" alt=""></a>
                    <a href="@"><img src="иконки/watsap.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
            
        </div>
    </div>
     <script src="js/favorites-script.js" defer></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

and this favorites-script.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // Check if the current page is the favorites page
  const favoritesPage = document.getElementById('favorites-page');
  if (!favoritesPage) {
    // If not the favorites page, exit the script
    return;
  }

  // Get the favorites from localStorage or an empty array if not present
  let favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
  console.log('Favorites:', favorites);

  // Function to render the favorites on the page
  function renderFavorites() {
    favoritesPage.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the existing content

    favorites.forEach(itemId => {
      const itemIdNumber = Number(itemId);
      const itemInMainPage = document.querySelector(`.block[data-id="${itemIdNumber}"]`);

      if (itemInMainPage) {
        const name = itemInMainPage.querySelector('.text h3').innerText;
        const description = itemInMainPage.querySelector('.text p').innerText;
        const price = itemInMainPage.querySelector('.text h4').innerText;

        const item = document.createElement('div');
        item.className = 'block';
        item.innerHTML = `
          <img src="gridlayout/img${itemIdNumber}.jpg" alt="${itemIdNumber}" >
          <div class="text">
            <i class="favorite-icon fas fa-heart"></i>
            <h3>${name}</h3>
            <p>${description}</p>
            <h4>${price}</h4>
          </div>
        `;

        favoritesPage.appendChild(item);
        console.log(`Rendered item with ID ${itemIdNumber}`);
      } else {
        console.log(`Item with ID ${itemIdNumber} not found in the favorites page`);
      }
    });
  }

  // Initial rendering of favorites on page load
  renderFavorites();
});
```

In favorites page supposed to be appear blocks of items with image,name,description and price but in console log says that items dont found in favorites page(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Ok, and when you test, using dev tools, do you observe favorites being succesfully recorded in localStorage `'favorites'` ?

Comment: `renderFavorites()` is looking for `class="block" data-id="X"` elements in the favorites page. They only exist in the main page, not the favorites page.